# TableView doesn't reload when making request

Tags: json, tableview, nsurlsession, alamofire

This is my code:

```
 func getMyData(){

    view.userInteractionEnabled = false

    let requestGetMyData = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"https://www.somewebsite.com/api/getMyData.php")!)

    let bodyData = "token="+token

    requestGetMyData.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    requestGetMyData.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let taskGetMyData = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(requestGetMyData, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        var jsonResponse = JSON(data: data!)

        for var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.count; i++ {

            self.myDataArray.append(jsonResponse[i]["dataText"].stringValue)

            self.myDataId.append(jsonResponse[i]["idData"].stringValue)

            self.myDataDate.append(jsonResponse[i]["date"].stringValue)

            self.myDataPhraseArray.append(jsonResponse[i]["phrase"].stringValue)

            self.myDataMyIdArray.append(jsonResponse[i]["id"].stringValue)

            self.myRepliesNumberArray.append(jsonResponse[i]["repliesNumber"].stringValue)

        }

        self.myDataTable.reloadData()

        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true


    })

    taskGetMyData.resume()
```

This is placed in viewDidLoad, when I open the view the table is empty, but if I scroll it, the data is shown. Why doesn't the table fill when the view loads but when I scroll it?

Plus: with Alamofire everything works okay. The data is displayed when the view loads.

edit: I'm realizing that the data is shown after 1 minute I reload the data (pullTorefresh, that execute func getMydata()). but with Alamofire, as I told before, shows immediately.

What's happening?

Comment: Might have something to do with the number of rows in the table on viewDidLoad - if it's 0? Have you tried viewWillAppear?

Comment: @remus I don't think the issue to be that you say because the data loads  when I scroll the table, it sounds a joke! Putting the code in viewWillAppear doesn't work.

Comment: Darn, yeah it was a longshot. Your code looks solid, so the fact that it's not drawing properly makes me think there's something else going on that's hijacking the drawing of the table. What about using a `dispatch_after` and delaying the reload by a second or so?

Comment: I'd not to use that patch because with Alamofire everything works fine! it has to be another solution. Anyway, how would dispatch_after have to be used?

Comment: Are you saying that the reloadData actually works once the AF response is received? If not, then something like `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        });`

Comment: @remus Could you tell exactly where have I to put that code in Swift 2.0 version?

Comment: right where you're reloading the tableview

Comment: Done. now Xcode says 'Use of unresolved identifier int64_t and ^ is not a prefix unary operator

Comment: Just try typing `dispatch_after` and let the autocomplete fill it out for you.

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't work. It is weird because when I load the view the table is empty, but if I scroll the table, the data loads, and when I do nothing, after one minute, all data is shown.